# php write statement IF ELSE condition interval/range

Tags: php

I have a problem in writing interval condition inside IF ELSE: This is my condition :

```
if(1<x<=30)
{ statement } 
else
{ statement }
```

Comment: `if ($x > 1 && $x < 30) { /* do something */ ] else { /* do other thing */ }`

Comment: You need to update your condition like as `if($x > 1 && $x <= 30)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check interval/range then you can do it using following:

```
if($x > 1 && $x <= 30){
  statement 
}else{
  statement       
}
```

Comment: you earn my vote... friend. and sorry we are on same page

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
if(1 < $x AND $x <= 30)
    echo true;
else
    echo false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this::

```
if(1<x && x<=30)
{ statement } 
else
{ statement }
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple case, Ternary operator is best in practise.

```
$result  = ($x > 1 && $x<=30) ? true : false;
```